# Php login is not showing true or false

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

```js
<?php
session_start();
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
// configuration
$dbhost  = "localhost";
$dbname  = "members";
$dbuser  = "root";
$dbpass  = "";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data

$email = $_POST['uemail'];
$password = $_POST['upassword'];

if($email == '') {
 $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Email';
 $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
 $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Password';
 $errflag = true;
}

// query
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email AND password");
$result->bindParam($email);
$result->bindParam($password);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if($rows > 0) {
header("location: newfeeds.php");
}
else{
 $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email and Password are not found';
 $errflag = true;
}
if($errflag) {
 $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
 session_write_close();
 header("location: index.php");
 exit();
}

?>
```

```html
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
   <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

       <?php
        if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array      ($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
 echo '<ul style="padding:0; color:red;">';
 foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
  echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
 }
 echo '</ul>';
 unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
        }
       ?>
 <form class="pop" method="post" action="login.php">
       
        <p class="login">LOGIN</p>
        <div class="form-group">
              <div class="left-inner-addon "><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>
           <input type="email" name="uemail" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                  </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
          <div class="left-inner-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
            <input type="password" name="upassword" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
        </div>
        <p>Forgot Password?</p>
      
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" role="button" name="login" id="login">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
    </form>   
</div>
    </div> 
      
   
<!-- form-->
```

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `memberID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have seen everywhere have the same issue of login not showing true login or false. I have type all these answers but that didn't work. Mostly register is working awesome with encrypt password and it stored well in the database. About login form, it sound crazy I have been post it so many times and correct it but I want to get the right answer. It should redirect after user logged in to another page and I should know that after user logged it is possible to store in different table in the same database.

**EX**: for register `users (id, username, email, password, gender)` and for `user_login table (id, email and password)`. Im new to sql and php and still struggling to get good answers. Please help and use the same variables of what I put in.

Comment: Your problem lies here: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email AND password`

Comment: what is the problem is this line?

Answer (score 0):

Please bind the variables correctly.

Change your query to

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND    password = :password");
$result->bindParam(':email', $email);
$result->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

Comment: Same error as above I wrote to @felix. I have paste yours too.